# Yet Another Query About the Thread Safety of a (Java) Singleton

Tags: java, thread-safety, singleton

Consider the following:

```
public class Singleton {
  private static Singleton instance;
  // NO INSTANCE VARIABLES

  private Singleton() {
    super(); // Just to have something to write here.
  }

  public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new Singleton();
    }
    return instance;
  }

  public String parseSomething(MyObject myObject) {
    // Do stuff
  }

  public void doAnotherThing(String value) {
    // Do something else
  }
}
```

Are `parseSomething()` and `doAnotherThing()` thread-safe? In other words, if I have multiple threads getting the `Singleton` instance and making possibly simultaneous calls to those two methods, will it end lives?

My instinct (and limited experience) says "no," because those methods do not act on anything outside their scope; they do not carry state in any instance variables in `Singleton`. Each calling thread would have the parameters and locally-scoped variables in their own stack, so (in theory) they shouldn't collide.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to Google up any questions on this topic that *don't* involve some action by the instance methods on a state-carrying instance variable in `Singleton`.

**Edit:** Trying the `instance` thing again. My real question here, though, is, assuming N threads have a handle on the `instance` and are making calls to `parseSomething()` and `doAnotherThing()`, will they murder each other?

Comment: Even `getInstance` is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are parseSomething() and doAnotherThing() thread-safe?

Highly depends, on what they do, and how they do it, **singleton pattern, has nothing to do with thread safety**, it supposed to guarantee that there is only one instance of the object in the running system, which by the way this implementation does not (You can create another instance of Singleton, using reflections, or if getInstance is called in parallel on getInstance call).

So, if this methods are stateless, and do not have any shared state, then they are thread safe. You can just make those methods static in your singleton class, and make a utility class out of this Singleton.

Comment: Perhaps I over-complicated things by adding the singleton aspect. The scenario is really just "N threads have a handle on the same instance of an object, and they are all calling its instance methods. If these instance methods do not access any variables outside of their own scopes, are they then thread-safe?"

Comment: @RandomHuman: do they access other external resources (files, sockets, ...)?

Comment: If they do not share any state (including files, sockets, e t.c.), they are thread safe, it would be easier, if you would provide a code, instead of guessing

Comment: @ninjalj Had to look at my *real* code for a minute there, but no. There are no external dependencies in this case. All code in the instance methods act only on the passed in parameters or locally-instantiated variables.